Is it possible to use LINQ to query for elements occuring in a certain sequence?
This is hard to search for as a non-native English speaker, as any search terms I come up with results in lots of questions related to OrderBy(Descending), and not what I am after.
Imagine I have a Thing, and this thing has a collection of ThingEvent objects. Now I want to query for Thing objects that have events occurring in a certain order.
var result = things.Where(t => 
                        t.ThingEvents
                         .Has( te => te.EventType == 1 )
                         .FollowedBy( te => te.EventType == 2 )
                    )
                    .ToList();

This is simple psuedo-code only to illustrate a point. Thing.ThingEvents is a collection ala IEnumerable, so Has() and FollowedBy() are two imaginary LINQ methods that help me do the following:

Verify that the given predicate is true - in this respect they are the same as the Where() LINQ method.
In the case of FollowedBy, that this happens AFTER a previous "match" in the sequence.

The last part is what trips me up - it means we need the ThingEvents collection to contain ThingEvents in a certain order (this collection is sorted correctly by the time we get to this query).
A collection containing eventtypes [1,2] would match. So would [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] and [1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2]. But [2,1,1,1,1,1] would not match - because at no point does an event type of 2 happen after an event type of 1.
Is it possible to query like this given the built-in LINQ methods?
If not, would it even be possible to build something like this by extending LINQ itself? Where my understanding breaks down with regards to solving this is that a method like Where() returns a simple boolean stating if the queried item meets the given predicate or not, my imagined Has() and FollowedBy() would do the same, but still pass on the "context" of where they are in the list to the following methods. Of course there could be other similar methods as well (PrecededBy() for instance).
Am I trying to do something that LINQ was not designed to do here? Or am I going about it all wrong? Or perhaps missing something pretty basic?
Thanks for any insights!
EDIT: I tried to be precise, but there are always some details escaping and adding confusion. :)
As some have pointed out, in my example it is not clear if "FollowedBy" means "is followed immediately by" (i.e. the very next item is...), or if it just means "any later item is...". My original intention was the latter, but your questions have enlightened me to see that there could probably be a need for both.
To add some context to perhaps make it easier to see the usefulness of what I am searching for: There can be many of these "Thing" objects, for a normal query there would be a couple of hundred, but it could be several thousand if aggregating more data. And each Thing object has between 0 and 20 ThingEvent objects.
Thing etc. lives in library code, and the use for the above is for users trying to read and create statistical information from the database of Thing objects. A certain subset of these will be in memory, and the user will be looking for information like "Does it EVER happen that event type 2 happens after event type 1 for a Thing?" - which is what my feeble attempt at psuedo code above represents.
There could of course be any number of ways they want to query this, and LINQ makes MOST of them easy. What I didn't find an easy solution for is the bit about also querying about their "spatial" position relative to each other in the collection, list, whatever.
As some have pointed out, multiple enumerations is a good thing to avoid. Is IEnumerable the wrong abstraction for this? Would I need something similar that also adds awareness of position of last and current item? I love the flexibility of LINQ, but of course I don't want to have to recreate it in order to give users ultimate flexibility. Or do I?
SECOND EDIT: Besides the point, but a shower thought this morning was that this could probably be solved easily by... regular expressions! (Yes, this abandons the dream of an elegant LINQ solution).
Say you have only 10 event types, so we assign them the character 0 through 9. The Thing object would have a conversion from its event collection to a string of these event types. Then we could easily construct a regex to match quite complex variants, such as "1.*2" for FollowedBy(), or just "12" for FollowedImmediatelyBy(). I might actually explore this as an easier way to attain the flexibility I want, even if it would be slightly more complex than this trivial example. If this incidentally helps prove that a RegEx can actually make solving a problem easier and I win a Nobel price, the beer is on me!

Do [1, 2, 1] (extra 1), [1, 1, 2, 2, 2] (two many 2), [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] (too many 1) match?

Yes to all questions - the only thing that matters in the given psuedo-code is three things: The list has a 1, the list has a 2, and at least one 2 comes after at least one 1.

@RuneJacobsen Does it need to come immediately after then previous value, or at any point in the following sequence?

@MathiasR.Jessen In the code example in the question, I would expect [1,3,2] to return true, i.e. followed, but not immediately followed by. However, you raise an interesting point - it could of course be interesting to be able to specify both "Followed immediately by", and potentially "Followed by, but NOT immediately". :)

Ah - my answer is specifically about "immediately followed by". I'll edit accordingly...

Always containing 2 elements?

@shingo: No, the number of elements both in the objects queried and in the query itself will vary. I will edit the question a bit to make it more clear.

The first thing to do would be to filter out all Things that don't have both ThingEvent 1 and ThingEvent 2.  This would reduce your iterations.  The second can't be done without knowing the definition of follows.  If it is just an array with numbers and you don't care about immediate follows then get first ThingEvent 1 index then get the maximum ThingEvent 2 index.  If the ThingEvent 2 index > ThingEvent 1 index, then it follows.

My answer just returns essentially true/false to say whether the pattern exists. It's unclear to me what behavior you really want. Do you want it to return the pattern items and then everything following in the sequence? Or return the sequence items that follow the pattern match?

@WellerEE Interesting approach. It looks like it would work for the example given, however, what about if a client chained multiple FollowedBy()? In that case we couldn't filter as we don't know what the next one might look for, right?

@JimMischel: Ideally I would love to have my cake and eat it too; Have these imaginary methods work as LINQ predicates like Where, to act as sequence ordering aware filters. But like you, I am unsure if that can be done with "pure" LINQ. We need it both to return true if there is a match, but also return the sequence so we can chain multiple filters... I don't have the brain to know how yet.

Note: I'd initially interpreted "following" as "immediately following", i.e. you wanted a pairwise condition. It looks like that isn't actually the case, but I'll leave this answer so that anyone finding the question actually looking for a pairwise condition is helped.
Assuming the collection can be safely iterated multiple times, you can use a combination of Zip/Skip to look at pairs. So for example:
var result = things.Where(t => 
    t.ThingEvents
     // This produces a sequence of 2-element tuples
     .Zip(t.ThingEvents.Skip(1))
     .Any(pair => pair.Item1.EventType == 1 && pair.Item2.EventType == 2));

I think that does what you want. It gets more fiddly if you need more than two elements, of course.
If you need this frequently, you probably could build Has/FollowedBy, but designing that would at least be non-trivial. (Ideally you'd do so in a way which only iterated the collection once.)

Thanks Jon (also for the books, big fan!). I edited the question a bit, hopefully for added clarity. I read your blog posts about re-creating the LINQ operators back in the day, perhaps I need to re-read that to see if it contains clues about what would be needed to create Has / FollowedBy and similar methods. I would not need a lot of them, but they would need to know about each others relative positions etc. I guess.

(Update: Adding predicate support was easy.)
I created two LINQ extension methods: Has and FollowedBy. For example:
var rslt = sequence
    .Has(t => t == 5)
    .FollowedBy(t => t >= 8)
    .FollowedBy(t => t < 3)
    .Any();

The return value is a single-item sequence on success: an empty sequence (Enumerable.Empty, essentially) on failure.
This is a little less than ideal. I'd like it to return a Boolean result, but the function chaining expects Has to return an IEnumerable so that FollowedBy can chain. I don't see how to resolve that. But the call to Any() fixes the problem.
Code below. This is just a proof of concept.
using System.Collections;

namespace HasLinqExtension
{
    public static class HasLinqExtension
    {
        public static IHasEnumerable<TSource> Has<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Predicate<TSource> target)
        {
            return new HasEnumerable<TSource>(source, target);
        }

        public static IHasEnumerable<TSource> FollowedBy<TSource>(this IHasEnumerable<TSource> source, Predicate<TSource> target)
        {
            source.AddPredicate(target);
            return source;
        }


        public interface IHasEnumerable<TSource>: IEnumerable<TSource>
        {
            public HasEnumerable<TSource> AddPredicate(Predicate<TSource> patternItem);
        }

        public class HasEnumerable<TSource> : IHasEnumerable<TSource>
        {
            private readonly IEnumerable<TSource> _source;
            private readonly List<Predicate<TSource>> _predicates = [];
            public HasEnumerable(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Predicate<TSource> target) 
            {
                _source = source;
                _predicates.Add(target);
            }

            public HasEnumerable<TSource> AddPredicate(Predicate<TSource> target)
            {
                _predicates.Add(target);
                return this;
            }

            public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
            {
                var ip = 0;
                foreach (var t in _source)
                {
                    if (_predicates[ip](t))
                    {
                        ip++;
                        if (ip == _predicates.Count)
                        {
                            yield return default;
                            yield break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
    }
}


This is a very interesting approach! I have been trying to look for any reason why a user would ever want a lookup in the other direction, and I have not yet come up with it (also keeping YAGNI close to my heart). This might very well be more than good enough!

@RuneJacobsen A lookup in the other direction could easily be accomplished by mySequence.Reverse().Has(...).FollowedBy(...) ...

@RuneJacobsen Also, with this approach you should be able to tailor the output (in GetEnumerator) to your tastes. At least to some extent. I don't have a good idea for how to make it return two values (i.e. the sequence and a Boolean result).

Assuming gaps are allowed between matching items, you could use SkipWhile to scan ahead to the next possible matching value and then test, skip, and move on to the next element:
public static class LinqExtensions {
  public static bool HasSequentialElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Predicate<T>[] predicates) 
    where T : IEquatable<T> {
    try {
      foreach(var predicate in predicates){
        source = source.SkipWhile(item => !predicate(item));
        if (!predicate(source.First())) return false;
        source = source.Skip(1);
      }
      return true;
    }
    catch {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

Then pass the appropriate predicates as arguments to HasSequentialElements:
bool satisfied = t.ThingEvents.HasSequentialElements(
  te => te.EventType == 1,
  te => te.EventType == 2
);


Thanks, Mathias, this is a very interesting approach, and even supports many predicate params! I shall play and see if it works the way my minds' compiler thinks! :)

It seems that you are looking for Lag, which is not implemented (at least in .Net 9) in the standard Linq yet.
We can do it manually as
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<(T Current, T? Prior)> Lag<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T? skip = default) {

    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

    var prior = skip;

    foreach (var current in source) {
      yield return (current, prior);

      prior = current;
    }
  }
}

and then use it like this:
var result = things
  .Where(t => t
     .ThingEvents
     .Lag()
     .Any(pair => pair.Prior?.EventType == 1 && pair.Current.EventType == 2));  

If we want standard Linq and just one pass (multiple iterations are not allowed), I vote for Aggregate;
var result = things.Where(t => t.ThingEvents
    .Aggregate(0, (state, item) => state = // state 0 - no 1 has found
        state == 0 && item == 1 ? 1        // state 1 - has 1, but no 2
      : state == 1 && item == 2 ? 2        // state 2 - 1 is followed by 2 
      : state) == 2);


Note that it looks like this interprets "following" as "immediately followed" - just as I did in my answer. It now sounds like that's not the actual requirement...

Thanks, Dmitry, as Jon points out the meaning of "following" was a bit unclear in the original post, but your Lag implementation certainly is interesting to wrap my head around!
